# Replace long list of 'If Activecell.value = X' with an array?

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a macro to search through a column of text and remove values that match the text in the macro below (when the text matches the entire row is deleted). The list of values to remove is around 140 unique numbers, and I have listed 5 below as an example.

What would be a simplified way of writing this portion of code rather than writing 'Activecell.Value = XXXX Or _' 140 times?

I was researching ways to use an array to store all the values I want deleted however I was not able to implement it properly.

Thanks for the help!

```
Sub DeleteClosedStores()

Range("F7").Select

While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    If ActiveCell.Value = 25401 Or _
        ActiveCell.Value = 8587 Or _
        ActiveCell.Value = 8275 Or _
        ActiveCell.Value = 8518 Or _
        ActiveCell.Value = 8522 Or Then

        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   End If
Wend
```

Comment: Dont loop. Use AutoFilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your macro like this:

```
Sub DeleteClosedStores()
Range("F7").Select
Dim KillArray
KillArray = Array(25401, 8587, 8275,8518,8522)
Dim f As Variant
While ActiveCell.value <> ""
    f = Filter(KillArray, ActiveCell.value)
    If UBound(f) <> -1 Then
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Of course @sarvesh is right. You need to enter your values somewhere.

Comment: This works great! Thank you for the help. One quick question: what is the Dim f as Variant doing in the code? I'm not familiar with using filters in VBA.

Comment: Not sure if this is realy needed. I have a background with strict programming languages so I declare types just as a reflex.

Comment: If you need help for a specific Function in VBA just mark the Keyword and press F1. Note that you have to install VBA-Help in the setup programm. If you don't have, install it!

Comment: Never knew that - very helpful tip.

Answer (score 0):

store all these values in a VB integer array and compare all values using `For...Next` loop.
But still you have to type all these 140 values at least once to store in an array.

Comment: Thank you - I'll give this a shot. Although I'll still have to type out all of the values I wanted to eliminate the redundancy of having so many 'ActiveCell.Value ='

Comment: using Loop you can eliminate this redundancy. But each value has to be typed, you can't avoid it if values have no mathematical relations.

Answer (score 0):

I would at least use the Cells property of the sheet. This method iterates over the cells, instead of moving the ActiveCell. It would be considerably faster than moving the active cell.

```
Private Sub deleteRows()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 7
    While Cells(i, "F").value <> ""
        If checkCondition(Cells(i, "F").value) Then
            Cells(i, "F").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub

Private Function checkCondition(value As String) As Boolean
    ' assuming everything is a number
    num = CLng(value)
    checkconditionmet = IIf(num = 25401 Or _
                            num = 8587 Or _
                            num = 8275 Or _
                            num = 8518 Or _
                            num = 8522, True, False)
End Function
```

This is O(n), but if you wanted to pre-load the cells into a variable, then iterate over that variable, that would be O(n) as well (O(n) + O(n)). But you don't want to iterate twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (btw, avoid usign `Select` and `ActiveSth` statements. It makes your code slow):

```
Sub DeleteClosedStores()
    Dim str1 As String
    Dim rng As Range

    str1 = "|25401|8587|8275|8518|8522|"

    Set rng = Range("F7")
    While rng.Value <> ""
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
        If InStr(1, str1, "|" & rng.Offset(-1) & "|") > 0 Then
            rng.Offset(-1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

The main idea is to split your values using e.g. "|" like this: `str1 = "|25401|8587|8275|8518|8522|"`, then sandwich your `rng.Value` with "|" like this `"|" & rng.Offset(-1) & "|"` (e.g if value of `rng.Offset(-1)` is `8587`, than code will tries to find `|8587|` in `|25401|8587|8275|8518|8522|`).

Comment: Interesting approach - I would've never thought to write it like this. Thanks for giving me another way to look at the solution - I'm going to implement it as a test and work my way through it to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Non-looping answer will be quicker

This one uses a working column with a test to delete the matching rows with an `AutoFilter` (excepting headers in row 1)

```
Sub KillEm()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
    Set rng1 = Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    Set rng2 = Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    Set rng3 = Range(Cells(rng2.Row, rng1.Column), Cells(1, rng1.Column))
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With rng3.Offset(0, 1)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(COUNTIF(RC1,{25401,8587,8275,8518,8522}))=1"
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="TRUE"
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng3.Rows.Count - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete            
        .EntireColumn.Delete           
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```